# Angular UI basic modal not working (demo from docs - with jsfiddle)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to learn angular ui and copy pasted a demo from their website into a jsfiddle. For some reason it's not working and not giving an error. Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

If you go into the jsfiddle below and then click the open button nothing happens and there is no error.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/baswg1wz/1/

Javascript:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
});

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For testing angularjs code you can use Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ExpguXeUAL7yqhJhuFsI?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not giving any errors because you didn't bootstrap your Angular application. You should wrap your entire html in a div (in a real page you should do this on the html or body tag) and then use the ng-app attribute to initialize/bootstrap your application:

```
<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
    <!-- your html -->
</div>
```

Also i noticed you didn't include the right ui library, you're using:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
```

You should be using: (also note the http://)

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

Furhermore, when using Angular in JSFiddle you should use the `no wrap - in <head>` option.

That should get you a lot further, but i would recommend using Plunker, if you checked the modal example on the ui.bootstrap site you could have noticed the blue `Edit in plunker` on the topright of the code, try clicking that.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: @iH8 - about the `//` notation, it will search for https and http version and apply the correct one, that is definitely not a mistake.